# AzureMetrics Table vs Metrics in Azure Dasboard

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks, azure-dashboard

I am working on Azure Monitor Dashboards.

I need to check the Health Status of my App Service.

If i run use option Metrics (2nd Image) add Health Status metrics and create chart
vs

If i run query on AzureMetrics Table  will both return same result? I mean HOW both options are different from each other?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both use the same source. The difference is that using the "Metrics" blade you can create charts withouth having to write queries using Kusto and anyone with basic knowledge can quickly create charts.

When using the "Logs" blade you have to write a query using Kusto to get the desired results and format the chart manually but you have more control in what and how data is displayed.

Comment: AND logs has custom settings for how long data can be retained (you can pay to store data for years if you want/need), whereas metrics are calculated and aggregated and are not stored long term (93 days max).  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/data-platform-metrics#retention-of-metrics

Answer (score 1):

> If i run query on AzureMetrics Table will both return same result? I
> mean HOW both options are different from each other?

The difference between logs and metrics is,

> ***Metrics reveal a service or application's tendencies and proclivities,
> while logs focus on specific events. The goal of logs is to save as
> much information—mostly technical informations—as possible about a
> single event. Log data can be used to investigate occurrences and
> assist with root-cause analysis of problems or defects, as well as an
> increasing number of other applications.***

For more information please refer the below links:-

**MSFT TECHCOMMUNITY**|[***Difference between Log Analytics and Monitor***](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-observability/difference-between-log-analytics-and-monitor/m-p/1291194)

**Blogs**|[***Azure Monitor and Azure Log Analytics***](https://samcogan.com/azure-monitor-and-azure-log-analytics-when-to-use-which/) & [***Logs or Metrics***](https://logz.io/blog/logs-or-metrics/#:%7E:text=While%20metrics%20show%20the%20tendencies,possible%20on%20a%20specific%20occurrence.).